# How do I check a list of c++/cli ref items for equality?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, equals, equality

A c++/cli ref class `DataEntity` implements Equals and HashCode. I can check the behavior of the `Equals` implementation via:

```
entity1.Equals(entity2);
```

(C# source) and it works correctly. 
If I now have a list of such DataEntities and I call `list1.Equlas(list2)`, the `DataEntity#Equals` method never gets called.

What is the reason for, and how can I use the List.Equals(...) method correcty?

---

C++/CLI source:

```
public ref class DataEntity : System::Object
{
public:
    DataEntity(System::String^ name, 
        System::String^ val) 
        : m_csName(name),
        m_csValue(val) {}

    System::String^ GetName() { return m_csName; }
    System::String^ GetValue() { return m_csValue; }
    virtual bool Equals(Object^ obj) override {
        if(!obj){
            return false;
        }
        DataEntity^ other = (DataEntity^)obj;
        if(other){
            if(m_csName->Equals(other->m_csName) &&
                m_csValue->Equals(other->m_csValue)){
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    virtual int GetHashCode() override {
        const int iPrime = 17;
        long iResult = 1;
        iResult = iPrime * iResult + m_csName->GetHashCode();
        iResult = iPrime * iResult + m_csValue->GetHashCode();
        return iPrime;
    }

private:
    System::String^ m_csName;       
    System::String^ m_csValue;
};
```

C# Unit test case **which fails!**

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    DataEntity de1 = new DataEntity("A", "B");
    List<DataEntity> des1 = new List<DataEntity>();
    des1.Add(de1);
    List<DataEntity> des2 = new List<DataEntity>();
    des2.Add(de1);

    Assert.IsTrue(des1.Equals(des2));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` doesn't override `Object.Equals`. Therefore, you get the default implementation of Equals, which is reference equality.

In order to test if the list *contents* are equal, you need to iterate the lists and compare each element, or use the Linq method mentioned in the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

In case of unit testing there is a utility method called:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedList, actualList);
```

which simplifies it a lot.